# Oracle- Update multiple tables with same column name

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Hi there I am new to oracle I am looking for a good way to convert my MySQL query into Oracle SQL

here is the SQL from my MySQL:

```
update billing, kb_detail 
    set tanggal_penagihan = :tanggal_penagihan 
        is_change = :is_change 
where billing.no_billing_sap = :no_billing_sap 
  and billing.no_billing_sap = kb_detail.no_billing_sap
```

while I was reading the answers most ppl give, I found out that I need to use merge into syntax or make a loop and assign the column name one by one, is there any better way?
I mean like a simple way that MySQL update syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to update two tables in Oracle is to run two `UPDATE` statements:

```
update billing
    set tanggal_penagihan = :tanggal_penagihan 
where no_billing_sap = :no_billing_sap;

update kb_detail 
       is_change = :is_change 
where no_billing_sap =  :no_billing_sap;
```

If you wrap that in a transaction there won't be a difference to what you did in MySQL

Comment: thanks for the help man , you are the best horse with no name